# KendoUI Grid for AngularJS binding error from asp.net mvc controller. Success is not a function error

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui-grid

I attempt to do simple task using KendoUI grid for AngularJS in asp.new mvc application. It is binding data to grid from mvc controller.

asp.net mvc controller method:

```
public ActionResult GetCdcReport()
{
    var testJson =
        @"{ProductID:'1',ProductName:'Chai',UnitPrice:'18',UnitsInStock:'39',Discontinued:'false'}";

    var json = JObject.Parse(testJson);
    return new JSONNetResult(json);
}
```

angularjs service function:

```
    function getImportResultReport() {
        return httpPost('getCdcReport');
    }
```

code from component for data binding:

```
$scope.mainGridOptions = {
    columns: [
        { field: "ProductID", title: "ID" },
        { field: "ProductName", title: "Product Name" },
        { command: [{ template: "<button class='k-button' ng-click='showDetails(dataItem)'>Show details</button>" }] },
    ],
    pageable: true,
    dataSource: {
        pageSize: 5,
        transport: {
            read: function (e) {
                dataservice.getImportResultReport().
                success(function (data) {
                        e.success(data);
                    }).
                error(function (data, status) {
                        alert('something went wrong');
                    console.log(status);
                });
            }
        }
    }
};
```

I see that server method is called but in console i get following client error:

> dataservice.getImportResultReport(...).success is not a function

In similar question i read that:

> The $http legacy promise methods success and error have been
>   deprecated. Use the standard then method instead.

i replace binding code on:

```
$scope.mainGridOptions = {
    columns: [
        { field: "ProductID", title: "ID" },
        { field: "ProductName", title: "Product Name" },
        { command: [{ template: "<button class='k-button' ng-click='showDetails(dataItem)'>Show details</button>" }] },
    ],
    pageable: true,
    dataSource: {
        pageSize: 5,
        transport: {
            read: function (e) {
                dataservice.getImportResultReport().
                then(function (data) {
                        return data;
                    });
            }
        }
    }
};
```

After that I don't receive this error but grid stay without data.

Also i attempted do it like:

```
vm.mainGridOptions = {
            columns: [
                { field: "ProductID", title: "ID" },
                { field: "ProductName", title: "Product Name" },
                { command: [{ template: "<button class='k-button' ng-click='showDetails(dataItem)'>Show details</button>" }] },
            ],
            pageable: true
        };

$scope.mainGridOptions.DataSource = dataservice.getImportResultReport();
```

it is also not work.

What i'm doing wrong?

It is example from telerik site. If in binding logic replase `dataservice.getImportResultReport()` on `$http.jsonp('URL FROM EXAMPLE')` then it is work.

Comment: You are probably getting a full http.response object back, so if you're parameter name is data you actually want to return data.data.

Comment: data.data also don't work.